# Adding an Auto Delete for files to the end of a Script File

Tags: bash, terminal

So I have a script that takes the zip files in the 2 folders and unzips them into new folders which all works and runs fine

(Folder Names Changed)

But I want to first Know if it is possible to after the files have been unziped and placed in there right folders to then delete the old zip files so all I am left with is the folders and all the unziped files.

And second if it is how would I go about doing that I am new to writing scripts

thanks for any help you can provide

```
cd ~/Downloads/

mkdir -p -v "./prior/(Folder_Name_1)"
mkdir -p -v "./prior/(Folder_Name_2)"
mkdir -p -v "./prior/(Folder_Name_3)"

mkdir -p -v "./current/(Folder_Name_1)"
mkdir -p -v "./current/(Folder_Name_1)"
mkdir -p -v "./current/(Folder_Name_1)"

tar -xzvf "./prior/Name1.reports.tar.gz" -C "./prior/Folder_Name_1"
tar -xzvf "./prior/Name2.reports.tar.gz" -C "./prior/Folder_Name_2"
tar -xzvf "./prior/Name3.reports.tar.gz" -C "./prior/Folder_Name_3"

tar -xzvf "./current/Name1.reports.tar.gz" -C "./prior/Folder_Name_1"
tar -xzvf "./current/Name2.reports.tar.gz" -C "./prior/Folder_Name_2"
tar -xzvf "./current/Name3.reports.tar.gz" -C "./prior/Folder_Name_3"
```

Comment: You can use the `rm` command to remove files.  Have a look at: `man rm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this

```
rm "./prior/Folder_1"
rm "./prior/Folder_2"
rm "./prior/Folder_3"

rm "./current/Folder_1"
rm "./current/Folder_2"
rm "./current/Folder_3"
```

Comment: Perfect just what I wanted